# Solaris:Not able to check hastatus in VCS

Tags: solaris

I am running VCS on node1 and node2 on solaris OS on oracle virtual box.I have run below commands on both node:

```
bash-3.00# lltconfig
LLT is running

bash-3.00# lltstat -nvv|head
LLT node information:
    Node                 State    Link  Status  Address
   * 0 node1             OPEN
                                  e1000g1   UP      08:00:27:A8:58:92
                                  e1000g2   UP      08:00:27:12:F2:FC
     1 node2             CONNWAIT
                                  e1000g1   DOWN
                                  e1000g2   DOWN
```

but when i am running below i am finding error:

```
bash-3.00# hastatus -sum
VCS ERROR V-16-1-10600 Cannot connect to VCS engine
VCS WARNING V-16-1-11046 Local system not available
```

What could be the issue?

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple components in Veritas Clustering.  LLT is the "low level transport" facility and is one of the first layers started in the boot process.  The "had" daemon and other higher level components are started by different boot scripts.   For whatever reason, it seems that either nothing is running "hastart" on your servers or that the "hastart" is failing.

Symantec provides better support than most vendors and has good docs online.  Do a web search for your error codes.  Check your VCS logs (probably /var/VRTSvcs/log/engine_A.log) and your system logs (probably /var/adm/messages).